# Timed out recv producing both EAGAIN and ETIMEDOUT?

Tags: sockets, glibc

For a blocking `recv` with `SO_RCVTIMEO` set via `setsockopt`, what is the difference between `EAGAIN` and `ETIMEDOUT`?

I have a blocking `recv` which is occasionally failing, but it fails (returning -1) in different ways depending on the client which is connected to my server. One client produces "Resource temporarily unavailable", and the other produces "Connection timed out". The `socket` man page says

> if no data has been transferred and the timeout has been reached then
>   -1 is returned with errno set to EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK

with no mention of ETIMEDOUT. I'm guessing that one of the clients is still producing TCP keepalives, but I can't find any docs on this. I'm on Linux 3.10, Centos 7.5.

Comment: The clients must be running on different platforms. What are they?

Comment: @EJP: don't know - this is a mail server. One is a spammer, the other is running broken software :)

Comment: So these messages appear at the server? In that case ETIMEDOUT means that the path back to the client doesn't work, and it should appear on or after a `send()`. EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK occurs on a `recv()` as you describe.

Comment: @EJP: the log output is created when `recv` returns -1, so they're both definitely receives. I've attached `gdb` for the EAGAIN client, without a timeout, and confirmed it was hung in `recv`. Not tried for the ETIMEDOUT case, though.

Comment: And yes, both messages appear at the server, when logging what `recv` does

Comment: I understand that the errors are both on receives, but I said that the ETIMEDOUT appears *on or after* a `send()`.

Comment: But that would imply that `recv`, when it returns -1, leaves a previous `errno` unmodified. It has to return a new `errno`, and that `errno` is `ETIMEDOUT`. My `send` calls are also blocking, with `SO_SNDTIMEO`.

Comment: No it doesn't. `send()` is asynchronous. If it doesn't return -1, all that means is that data was transferred into the local socket send buffer. It is *sent*, or not sent, asynchronously, and if there was an error in that process it can only be delivered via the *next* system call. 'Blocking with `SO_SNDTIMEO`' is a contradiction in terms. It isn't clear that there is any problem here to solve.

Comment: Ok, thanks, if you want to answer that `ETIMEDOUT` is a response to a previous `send` I'll accept that. Not sure what you mean by the 'contradiction', though. The `send` is blocking, so will hang up if the buffer is full without an SO_SNDTIMEO, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ETIMEDOUT` is almost certainly a response to a previous `send()`. `send()` is asynchronous. If it doesn't return -1, all that means is that data was transferred into the local socket send buffer. It is sent, or not sent, asynchronously, and if there was an error in that process it can only be delivered via the next system call: in this case, `recv()`.

It isn't clear that there is any problem here to solve